# React: how to monitor the focus state of another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 separate components that are very "far" from each other (no parent-child relationship to pass props around):

1. A component that does a count-down and navigates away when timer is hit.
2. A text field down below the page.

I want to stop the timer when the user is editing the text field.

Besides saving an "isEditing" state into Redux or `window` (or some state management) from component #2, and monitoring that state from component #1, are there any standard React way to achieve this?

Perhaps there is a way for a `ref` to listen to another `ref`'s property change, such as `focus`?

Comment: Have you try to use react context ?

Comment: Are you able to show us what you have tried with a small, reproducible example? [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) is great for this.

Comment: Context. redux, window are all the same concept -- pushing the state into a state management, and the other components listens to it. These work and is my current solution, but I am looking at alternatives.  It doesn't make sense to push a GUI state (non-business logic) to the state management. Something lighter like perhaps listening to another component's "on focus" or "on scroll"